# Should I Wait for a Journal's Decision Before Revising Authorship?

Tags: publications, journal-workflow

I have submitted a paper to one of the Elsevier journals. My senior asked me to put him as a corresponding author, but I put myself as a corresponding author assuming it is possible to change corresponding author. However, she asked me to request journal editor to revert this immediately. I sent a request as my senior suggested, and I got response from the editor like this:

"There is a 90% chance your paper will be rejected, in which case it doesn't matter, and a 10% chance you will be invited to submit a revision".

The journal impact factor is 4.034, and their acceptance rate is 7%.

This is my first experience submitting paper to any journal, so I am afraid and wondering whether it is worth withdrawing the paper and proceeding to another journal.

Comment: Wow, that's an equally honest and unfriendly response. (but of course it's factually correct - worry about this when the paper actually is on the track to being accepted)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have been given the answer by the editor: That it doesn't matter yet.

Tell the other author of the paper that you asked, and the editor said to deal with it if/when you're asked to revise the paper.

Then move along with your life and work and wait for a reply. You absolutely *shouldn't* withdraw the paper for something like that when you've already been told how to handle it by the editor.